# seleccion de n elemento en un array sin repeticion de una posicion ja selecionada

Tags: python

Asumamos que tengo este codigo,

```
import random
mylist = ["A", "B", "A", "A" ]
print(random.choices(mylist, k = 2))
```

Me mostró en pantalla ["B", "B"]. Esto está correcto pero lo que necesito es que mostré en pantalla dos elementos del array sin repetición de una posición ya seleccionada. Por ejemplo ["A", "B"], ["A", "A"] ya que hay 2 A dentro array. Lo que no me puede selecciona son dos B ya que no hay dos B dentro del array. Muchas gracias

Comment: Usa `random.sample()` en vez de `random.choices()`. O también mezcla tu lista al azar (`mylist.shuffle()`) y luego coge los dos primeros elementos  (`mylist[:2]`)

Comment: Te aviso que se escribe "ya", no "ja". Lo podrás notar por que ambas palabras suenan diferente cuando las dices.